# Why does a printer's orientation setting get incorrectly reported by DocumentProperties() if program is executed from a windows service

Tags: windows, visual-c++, printing

I have a VC++ console app which has a function that reads the printer's current orientation setting. Using the sample code from [this MS page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167345/how-to-modify-printer-settings-with-the-documentproperties-function), I can successfully read the printer's setting when executing the program from the cmd prompt. However, if I execute it from a Windows service (written in C#), the current orientation would always return as 1 (portrait), even though the other settings look correct. Why is that?

**To summarize**: 
For a printer whose orientation is set to Landscape, the code below, if run from cmd.exe, correctly outputs:

> original printer orientation=2

but if run from a windows service written with C#, always outputs:

> original printer orientation=1

```
/*
* Step 1:
* Allocate a buffer of the correct size.
*/
dwNeeded = DocumentProperties(NULL,
    hPrinter,       /* Handle to our printer. */
    deviceName,        /* Name of the printer. */
    NULL,           /* Asking for size, so */
    NULL,           /* these are not used. */
    0);             /* Zero returns buffer size. */
pDevMode = (LPDEVMODE)malloc(dwNeeded);

/*
* Step 2:
* Get the default DevMode for the printer and
* modify it for your needs.
*/
dwRet = DocumentProperties(NULL,
    hPrinter,
    deviceName,
    pDevMode,       /* The address of the buffer to fill. */
    NULL,           /* Not using the input buffer. */
    DM_OUT_BUFFER); /* Have the output buffer filled. */
if (dwRet != IDOK)
{
    /* If failure, cleanup and return failure. */
    free(pDevMode);
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    return NULL;
}

cout << "original printer orientation=";
cout << pDevMode->dmOrientation;
```

Comment: Have you tried printing something? Perhaps different user means different settings and it is set to portrait mode for that user.

Comment: Yes, printing works fine. In fact, everything is fine including font name, size, copies, etc. Orientation is the only one that returns different values. I'm executing the program on my PC, and the Windows service also runs on my PC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to permissions. The Windows service was running under "Local System", which of course does not recognize the printer setting changes I made under my own logon name. Thanks to Retired Ninja who made me think of permissions.